# What is the difference between the id you get from logcat and AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR for testing?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I'm still testing my app ads and I use this code to generate test ads.

But I was wondering if there is any difference between using  `AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR` and using the id generated in logcat?

**Code I'm using**

```
adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would so encourage to just use [test ads provided by Google](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads).

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" : "yourRealAdUnitID");
```

So much simpler than messing around with multiple test devices.